# Sorting an Array of objects by Name, date, and balances

Tags: arrays, sorting, object, comparable

I need to sort an array of objects by order of first and last name. The objects have 4 fields: fName, lName, date, and balance. I need to be able to sort the array in order of the names but every time I try I find that my output matches the order that I originally put them into the array. I also need to implement the Comparable interface but every time I try I get an error saying I didn't override the method compareTo().

Here is my code as it stands:

```
 public static int compareTo(Account a, Account b)
 {
   String nameOne = a.getLName();
   String nameTwo = b.getLName();

   String name1 = a.getFName();
   String name2 = b.getFName();

   if(nameOne.compareTo(nameTwo) == -1)
   {   
       return  -1;
   }else if(nameOne.compareTo(nameTwo) == 1)
   {
       return  1;
   }else if(nameOne.compareTo(nameTwo) == 0)
   {
       if(name1.compareTo(name2) == -1)
          {
              return  -1;
          }else
           {
              return  1;
           }
   }else{
       return 1;
    }
   }
```

public static void main(String[] args)

```
{
    int  shortestStringIndex;

    Account[] accounts = new Account[5];
    Account[] sortedAccount = new Account[5];

    accounts[0] = new Account("John", "Myers", "6/11/1994", 100);
    accounts[1] = new Account("Bill", "Bane", "7/11/1994", 200);
    accounts[2] = new Account("Marcus", "Bane", "9/7/1033", 891);
    accounts[3] = new Account("Mike", "Rogers", "4/14/2014", 500);
    accounts[4] = new Account("Bill", "Philip", "7/11/1996", 600);

    for(int j=0; j < accounts.length - 1;j++)
        {
         shortestStringIndex = j;

         for (int i=j+1 ; i<accounts.length; i++)
         {

          if(compareTo(accounts[i],accounts[shortestStringIndex])<0)
          {
                 shortestStringIndex = i;  
          }
          }

         if(shortestStringIndex != j)
         {
             sortedAccount[0] = accounts[j];
             accounts[j] = accounts[shortestStringIndex]; 
             accounts[shortestStringIndex] = sortedAccount[0];
            }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<accounts.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(accounts[i].toString());
    }
}
```

Any help in getting the Comparable interface to implement or in sorting the are would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The method signature of `Comparable#compareTo` is `int compareTo(T o)` which is different from the signature you have implemented.  Yours takes 2 arguments, Comparable's takes only one.  Your `compareTo` should also be a member of the `Account` class.

Comment: How do I make the compareTo() a member of my Account class?

Comment: inside your Account class, add a method called compareTo with the same signature as the Comparable method